# React native Switch component does not update its state when switched to other tabs which already rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-context

I am using React native Switch component inside my header component (which is present in all the pages in my app).

When I change the value of Switch component in one tab and switch to another page, the change is not reflecting in headers in other pages.

This is the code I have written inside Header component.

```
function Header() {

const { colors } = useTheme();
const navigation = useNavigation();
const { state, dispatch} = useContext(VideoDataContext);
const [dark, setDark]= useState(state && state.dark);

const toggleTheme=()=>{
    dispatch({type:"theme", payload:{darkTheme:!state.dark}});
    setDark((prevState)=>!prevState);
}

return (
        ....
        <View style={styles.headerRight}>

            <Switch 
                trackColor={{ false: "black", true: "red" }}
                thumbColor={dark ? "#f4f3f4" : "#f4f3f4"}
                ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                onValueChange={toggleTheme}
                value={dark}
            />
            
            ...

        </View>
);
}
```

This is how I have used Header component in all the pages.

```
function Home(){
 
 ....

 return (
       <Screen>
           <Header />
              
           // Other components

       </Screen>
 )
}
```

Pictures:

1. Home page - I turned on the switch in header

[image]

2. Explore page - The switch is not getting updated

[image]

How can I update the switch in each pages based on state value?

Answer (score -1):

you are passing down a "value" param instead of a "checked" param to the switch to indicate if it's switched on or not depending on your state's value.

Something like would do:

```
<Switch checked={dark} ... />
```

Comment: I think React native Switch component does not have "checked" prop. Instead "value" prop is given to indicate if its switched on or not

Comment: You can try defaultChecked instead of checked